# Query framed using GenerateFilterConditionForDate changes time to UTC time in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

**My Problem**

Query framed using GenerateFilterConditionForDate changes time to UTC time.

**What I have done**

Below is the query used

```
var queryDtFrom = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filterJoin,
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("TimeReceived", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, fromDateTimeOffset));
```

The value passed for `frmDateTimeOffset` is  `{6/18/2018 5:00:00 PM}`

But the framed query `queryDtFrom` has the value as

```
 (PartitionKey eq 'D4AS3') and (TimeReceived ge datetime'2018-06-18T11:30:00.0000000Z')
```

Here the date value changes to `2018-06-18T11:30:00.0000000Z` while the passed value to `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate` is `{6/18/2018 5:00:00 PM}`

**My Requirement**

How could we make a query that'd  be framed with GenerateFilterConditionForDate to have the same passed dateTime in the resultant query
instead of changed UTC time value?
Any ideas, please share.

Comment: This is expected behavior as all the date/time type attribute values are stored in UTC.

Comment: Ok, but do we have in GenerateFilterConditionForDate, any property  or so to get back the same value passed in?

Comment: Since you're based out of India (GMT+5:30), instead of passing date/time offset as  `{6/18/2018 5:00:00 PM}`, you can pass `{6/18/2018 10:30:00 PM}` i.e. add 5:30 to your date/time offset value. That way it will be UTC `{6/18/2018 5:00:00 PM}`. But then you will end up getting incorrect data I think.

Comment: Hmm. What if we would want to store a fixed date value in the Table Storage and would later like to retrieve the actual value for some reference\process or so? Isn't there any way? coz with this - `GenerateFilterConditionForDate` - never we can get the actual value stored but a UTC converted date value.

Comment: One possibility would be to convert your date/time value as ticks and store that as Int64. Other option would be to store the date as string. My preference would be to store as ticks.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes this works well. Thanks. I shall mark this as an answer if you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments and other answer, this is the default behavior of Azure Tables. All date/time values are stored as UTC.

Again, as mentioned in comments, if you wish to preserve the date/time value, one possible solution would be to get `ticks` of the date/time value and store that value as an `Int64` type attribute. Before querying you can get ticks value for the date/time and use that for querying purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in Azure.

It advocates for storing in UTC time as it is the standard time in which you can calculate any other times zone off of.

We can convert our local zone time to UTC time first before we call `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate` as below:

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("6/18/2018 5:00:00 PM"),DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

As Gaurav Mantri commented above: "This is expected behavior as all the date/time type attribute values are stored in UTC". We can also convert UTC time to local zone time when we retrieve the date time of UTC format from table:

```
DateTime dt = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
```